# script no funciona en Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Buenas tengo un proyecto en angular en el que estoy probando varias cosas. 
he cargado un scrpit javascript en el index.html. Es una funcion de acordeon para un faqs.
En local funciona perfecta la funcion y el script de acordeon. Pero en producción no funciona bien la función de acordeon. Creo que es porque no esta cargando bien el script angular.

Aver si alguin me ayuda.

Os dejo el index.html donde tengo el script

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>App</title>
 <base href="/">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
</body>
<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("faqsAccordion");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
      panel.style.overflow = "auto";
    }
  });
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿El qué lugar estás cargando Angular? En el `HTML` veo solo un `script`, el cual está intentando acceder a elementos con la clase `faqsAccordion`, los cuales no existen así que infiero que los creas dinámicamente en algún otro lado.

Comment: si lo tengo en el html de un componente. En localhost funciona perfecto pero en el browser no. En localhost si pero en produccion Ni separandolo a un archivo externo de .js funciona

Comment: Bueno, este `HTML` por sí solo no hará nada, si tu código tiene más partes o más piezas lo debes explicar o al menos señalar cómo reproducirlo. Debes crear al menos [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Estas recibiendo algun error en consola cuando estas en produccion?